# Key Word in Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, bibliographystyle, footcite

I have following problem.
My professor wants me to have following footcite style and bibliography style.
[image: Footcitestyle]

[image: Bibliographystyle]

The footcite has got a keyword, in this case "Bilanzen" and this is displayed in the brackets in the bibliography.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle-ibid,giveninits=true,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\add\textbackslash\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\begin{filecontents}{myreferences.bib}
@book{bilanz,
    address = {D{\"u}sseldorf},
    author = {Baetge, J{\"o}rg and Kirsch, Hans-J{\"u}rgen and Thiele, Stefan},
    date-added = {2021-03-26 12:37:04 +0100},
    date-modified = {2021-03-29 16:08:56 +0200},
    edition = {14},
    publisher = {},
    title = {Bilanzen},
year = {2017}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}
\begin{document}
Im Handelsrecht gibt es bzgl. der weiteren Handhabung keine speziellen Vorgaben, daher muss auf das Steuerrecht und die Einkommensteuerrichtlinien zurückgegriffen werden. Bei Gebäuden muss zusätzlich die Art der Nutzung berücksichtigt werden.\footcite[Vgl.][S.35]{bilanz}\\
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So I know how to use to shorttitle, but how to include this into the bibliography I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code uses the approach `authoryear` takes to print the year directly after the names in the bibliography.

It is implied by your comment, but just to make it explicit: The solution is based on the automatically generated `labeltitle`, which can take its value from the `title` field or from `shorttitle`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authortitle-ibid,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nametitledelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \printnames{author}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}

\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editor+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}

\renewbibmacro*{translator}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translatorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{translator+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translator+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:translator}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{translator}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{translatortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{translator}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bilanz,
  address = {Düsseldorf},
  author  = {Baetge, Jörg and Kirsch, Hans-Jürgen and Thiele, Stefan},
  edition = {14},
  title   = {Bilanzen},
  year    = {2017},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill % only for the example
Im Handelsrecht gibt es bzgl. der weiteren Handhabung keine speziellen Vorgaben,
daher muss auf das Steuerrecht und die Einkommensteuerrichtlinien zurückgegriffen werden.
Bei Gebäuden muss zusätzlich die Art der Nutzung
berücksichtigt werden.\autocite[Vgl.][35]{bilanz}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Vgl. Baetge, J./Kirsch, H.-J./Thiele, S. (Bilanzen), S. 35.//Baetge, J./Kirsch, H.-J./Thiele, S. (Bilanzen): Bilanzen. 14. Aufl. Düsseldorf, 2017.]

Comment: That looks perfect. Thank you very very much for your quick help.